# Get Width of a layout inside a linearlayout

Tags: android, layout, width

I need to get the Width of a relativeLayout inside a LinearLayout.
the problem is that the relative is in 0dp of width and 0.9 of weight....
getWidth() and getMeasuredWidth return 0.
Anyone can help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Passing WRAP_CONTENT as value to makeMeasureSpec() doesn't to do any good, I don't think those were meant to be used together.

Use actual constraint value as first parameter (e.g. size of the parent view or dimensions of the screen) with the MeasureSpec.AT_MOST mode, which is basically Math.min() -- with arguments being the value you put in the spec and the view's desired dimension.

MeasureSpec.EXACTLY will make it use the spec value, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED will make it use the view's desired value. So if you don't have any constraints (like if you put your view into a ScrollView) your option is MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED -- and any value as first argument.

So, {gurus, correct me if I'm wrong} you get WRAP_CONTENT behavior with any mode other than MeasureSpec.EXACTLY

That being said, try:

```
ViewGroup view = ...;
view.setPadding(10, 0, 10, 0);
// Either this 
int specWidth = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(parentWidth, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
// Or this 
int specWidth = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0 /* any */, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
view.measure(specWidth, specWidth);
int questionWidth = view.getMeasuredWidth();
```

Comment: i didn't understand a word.
but i've solved this, simply using:

@Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        LinearLayout logo_top_linear=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.logo_top_linear);
        altezza_lobo_top=logo_top_linear.getHeight();
        larghezza_lobo_top=logo_top_linear.getWidth();
    }